# Polymer: Can't overwrite default font with custom property mixin

Tags: polymer

Can't overwrite default font (Roboto) using custom property mixin when any paper font mixins are referenced ie: @apply(--paper-font-sunhead); as it looks like nested CSS variables get confused.

Live example:
https://codepen.io/rhysyg03/pen/YxgYQp?editors=1100

```
<custom-style>
    <style>
    .my-class {
      --paper-font-common-base: {
                font-family: Georgia, Serif;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            }
    }
    </style>
</custom-style>
```

When a CSS variable is nested, in this example:

- font-family: var(--paper-font-subhead_-_font-family)
- refers back to
- font-family: var(--paper-font-common-base_-_font-family)

--paper-font-subhead_-_font-family variable refers back to variable in the same declaration (html) even if it’s been overwritten (.my-class).

Please help :)

Comment: Where have you defined `--paper-font-subhead` mixin?

Comment: I have referenced this in my Polymer component. For example .my-div { @apply(--paper-font-subhead);  }

Comment: I mean the definition like this `--paper-font-common-base: {
                font-family: Georgia, Serif;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            }` for `--paper-font-subhead`.

Comment: On the document that contains the Polymer element. If you check the codepen you can see an example.

Comment: You have applied the mixin `--paper-font-subhead` but you haven't defined. I double checked the codepen link.

Comment: --paper-font-subhead refers back to --paper-font-common-base, which I have defined. That's how it's intended to work easily I'm assuming. Why do I need to define it again at the document level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153825/discussion-between-rhys-and-ofisora).